# Relay response slow using Arduino via C# and PC USB

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm sending a command via C# from PC (directly via USB) to Arduino to trigger a relay switch. There is a delay of slightly less than a second for the relay to respond.  That delay is too long for my needs.

Is that a normal delay between PC and Arduino and relay switch or is there anything I can change in the codes below?

Below are my C# commands followed by the Arduino sketch

C#:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
    serialPort1.Open();
}
```

Button events:

```
private void btnSolenoid1On_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.Write("1");
}

private void btnSolenoid1Off_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.Write("0");
}
```

If I want to loop the ON/OFF commands above, I have to add a Sleep(1000) statement between the commands.  But that's too much of a delay.

ARDUINO SKETCH:

```
//Relay set to low from Arduino turns switch on; high turns it off
const int RELAY_1 = 22;
int intSolenoid1 = 0;
String strSolenoid1 = "";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(RELAY_1, OUTPUT);

    //Turn relay off at startup.
    digitalWrite(RELAY_1, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    while (Serial.available()>0) { //Wait for user input
    strSolenoid1 = Serial.readString();
    intSolenoid1 = strSolenoid1.toInt();
    switch (intSolenoid1)
    {
        case 0:
            digitalWrite(RELAY_1, HIGH);
            break;
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(RELAY_1, LOW);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i couldn't understand the statement 'If I want to loop the ON/OFF commands above, I have to add a Sleep(1000) statement between the commands. But that's too much of a delay'. Anyway I'd write `if (Serial.available()>0) { switch(Serial.read()) { case '0': ... break; case '1': ... break; } }`, since reading a string, converting it to an int and so on is just a waste of time and processor power...

Comment: Hey @Don, Where is the `Sleep` statement?

Comment: `C#` part is fine. Problem should be in `Arduino sketch`. Because you are using *polling* you can try to reduce interval at which you are polling or maybe there is a way to get informed when there is something available as interrupt/callback/event/whatever, then use that.

Comment: You are using a string to integer conversion in the sketch. I'm sure that is costing you some clock cycles there. You are only sending a byte so why use strings ? You could just read into a char or int and switch on that value. Not sure if the conversion is causing all of your delay but taking it out would not hurt.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  I was going to use the string later, but now understand where I was converting to int was not an efficient use of the serial read.  Vivek, regarding where the sleep statement is, it was part of my testing to find the problem.  I placed it immediately after sending the serialPort1.Write("1"); statement as my button event in C#.  Without it, the relay was not responding.  With it, it was too slow and anything less than a delay of one second would result in the relay not switching at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a flaw in the sketch. You want it to act on a single byte of data but you are reading a string. If there is more than one byte of data in the input buffer then all the bytes are being read in. For example, if you sent "0" then "1", then the readString could see "01", and the conversion of that to an int is 1. So essentially it would never see the off command. The opposite is also a problem. "10" would become an int 10 and fall through the case. Re- writing the sketch as @frarugi87 suggested:

```
while(Serial.available()>0) 
{ 
   switch(Serial.read()) 
   { 
     case '0': 
       digitalWrite(RELAY_1, HIGH);
     break; 

     case '1':
       digitalWrite(RELAY_1, LOW);
     break; 
   } 
}
```

would not only run faster, but also run as you intended.

Comment: Yes, the reason was that the readString function returned after a while (1 second is the default timeout), so it collected all of the bytes sent